# getting error while submitting a form using post method

Tags: python, django, api, django-csrf

**Error : CSRF token missing or incorrect.** Want to pass token to submit a form which is not on a django-template.

> views.py

```
....
def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        user = authenticate(email=email)
        if user is None:
            form.save()
            message = 'Saved Successfully'
            return HttpResponse(message)
        else:
            message = 'User Exists'
            return HttpResponse(message)
    else:
        message = 'Invalid form data'
        return HttpResponse(message)
....
```

> form.html

```
....
<h1>Register</h1>
<form class="newform" action="/api/register/" method='POST'enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value="some token value" />
    ....
</form>
....
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of CSRF (cross-site request forgery) protection is to prevent submitting forms that are not served by the same site. If you really need to serve html pages with forms from a different site, you'll have to disable CSRF protection. If you just need to create the form manually and serve it from the same site via a Django view, you can populate the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` field with JavaScript. First, extract a token from cookies as described in Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#ajax Then you can populate the field.

Example with JQuery:

```
$(function() {
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = $.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').attr('value', crsftoken);
});
```

Comment: either i disable it or use this function .  right ?

Comment: This piece if JS will work if you are serving ready-made html via a Django view (e.g. `TemplateView` CBV) on the very same Django site. Otherwise you'll have to disable CSRF protection and use other protection mechanisms, e.g. access tokens.

Comment: The entire webpage is not a part of this django app. How and where should i use this snippet? Actually this form appears onclick event and is present in js file.

Comment: Django has hardened CSRF protection designed to prevent exactly what you are trying to accomplish. In your case disable CSRF protection and use other methods to prevent unauthorized form submission.

Answer (score 0):

use {% csrf_token %} in your form:

```
<form>
{% csrf_token %}
<input ... >
</form>
```

Comment: {% csrf_token %} is used when you have to render the template. however I'm not using any templates. Well i have tried it, won't work.